# CodeIgniter: How to put custom validation function in model instead of controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CI's documentation, it says that you could create your own custom validation for use in form submission check. It shows how this can be done in a controller:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

**But what if I want to have my custom validation function in a model?**

I've found that the following did not work...

**BOTH FUNCTIONS BELOW ARE IN A MODEL:**

```
public function validate_form(){

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_illegal_username_check');

  $this->form_validation->run();

}
```

And here's my custom validation function:

```
public function illegal_username_check($string){

  if($string == 'fcuk'){

    $this->form_validation->set_message('illegal_username_check', 'Looks like you are trying to use some swear words in the %s field');
    return FALSE;

  }

  else{

   return TRUE;
  }

}
```

I found that because my custom validation function is in the model, it did not get called when I run my "validate_form()" function. How do I resolve this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put custom validation rules in a MY_Form_validation.php in the application/libraries folder.

Then, when you assign your rules you can do something like this..

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('field1', 'Field one name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|your_custom_validator');
```

Note the custom validator doesn't require the **callback_** keyword in front.

Here's an example My_Form_valdation.php file.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

 function __construct($rules = array()) {
    parent::__construct($rules);

    $this->ci = & get_instance();
    $this->ci->load->database();
}

function your_custom_validator($val) {


    $this->set_message('your_custom_validator', 'this isn\'t right!');

    return (!$val) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

Note in the construct I've got the Ci instance and loaded the database class.

To use it i'd do something like this..

```
  $this->ci->db->where('id', 1)->get('user')->row();
```

Comment: Thank you @Iglo. However, I'm not sure if I understand what this line does:

"$this->ci->db->where('id', 1)->get('user')->row();"

Can you please explain? Thanks!

Comment: That was just an example of using the database class. I wanted you to note that you need to add the $this->ci in-front of any function you want to call from the CI instance. 

So another example would be, if you wanted to get an input from here you would need to do $this->ci->input->post('something'); instead of $this->input->post('something');

Comment: Thanks very much @Iglo. It works :-) One last question: Why did you put "$rules = array()" in the constructor param?

Comment: The $rules need to be passed through the constructor and equal an empty array if there are none.